Suppress Duplicates in SQL Server Recursive Query
I've got a data structure where a record represents a person. A person can have a relationship to another person. There are different types of relationship so it's possible that there can be multiple relationships (each of a different type) between different people.
CREATE TABLE RelationshipTypes(
    Id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_RelationshipTypes PRIMARY KEY,
    TypeDesc VARCHAR(20)
);
GO

INSERT INTO RelationshipTypes(Id,TypeDesc) VALUES(1,'Supervisor');
INSERT INTO RelationshipTypes(Id,TypeDesc) VALUES(2,'Auditor');
INSERT INTO RelationshipTypes(Id,TypeDesc) VALUES(3,'Executor');

CREATE TABLE People(
    Id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_People PRIMARY KEY,
    FullName VARCHAR(20)
);
GO

INSERT INTO People(Id,FullName) VALUES(1,'David Jones');
INSERT INTO People(Id,FullName) VALUES(2,'Susan Smith');
INSERT INTO People(Id,FullName) VALUES(3,'John Williams');
INSERT INTO People(Id,FullName) VALUES(4,'Margaret Taylor');
INSERT INTO People(Id,FullName) VALUES(5,'Michael Brown');
INSERT INTO People(Id,FullName) VALUES(6,'Patricia Davies');
INSERT INTO People(Id,FullName) VALUES(7,'Paul Evans');
INSERT INTO People(Id,FullName) VALUES(8,'Sarah Thomas');
INSERT INTO People(Id,FullName) VALUES(9,'Andrew Wilson');
INSERT INTO People(Id,FullName) VALUES(10,'Elizabeth Johnson');

CREATE TABLE PeopleRelationships(
    Id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_PeopleRelationships PRIMARY KEY,
    SourcePeopleId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_PeopleRelationships_People1 REFERENCES People(Id),
    TargetPeopleId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_PeopleRelationships_People2 REFERENCES People(Id),
    RelationshipTypeId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_PeopleRelationships_RelationshipTypes REFERENCES RelationshipTypes(Id)
);
GO

INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(1,1,2,1);
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(2,1,2,3);
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(3,1,3,1);
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(4,2,4,2);
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(5,2,4,3);
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(6,2,5,1);
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(7,2,6,2);
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(8,3,7,3);
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(9,3,8,2);
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(10,3,8,3);
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(11,7,9,1);
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(12,7,9,3);
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId) VALUES(13,7,10,3);

If you run that, then run the following query
SELECT p1.Id SourcePeopleId,
       p1.FullName SourceFullName,
       rt.TypeDesc,
       p2.Id TargetPeopleId,
       p2.FullName TargetFullName
FROM PeopleRelationships pr
JOIN People p1 ON p1.Id = pr.SourcePeopleId
JOIN People p2 ON p2.Id = pr.TargetPeopleId
JOIN RelationshipTypes rt ON rt.Id = pr.RelationshipTypeId
ORDER BY p1.Id,p2.Id,rt.Id;

You get an idea of how things look



SourcePeopleId
SourceFullName
TypeDesc
TargetPeopleId
TargetFullName




1
David Jones
Supervisor
2
Susan Smith


1
David Jones
Executor
2
Susan Smith


1
David Jones
Supervisor
3
John Williams


2
Susan Smith
Auditor
4
Margaret Taylor


2
Susan Smith
Executor
4
Margaret Taylor


2
Susan Smith
Supervisor
5
Michael Brown


2
Susan Smith
Auditor
6
Patricia Davies


3
John Williams
Executor
7
Paul Evans


3
John Williams
Auditor
8
Sarah Thomas


3
John Williams
Executor
8
Sarah Thomas


7
Paul Evans
Supervisor
9
Andrew Wilson


7
Paul Evans
Executor
9
Andrew Wilson


7
Paul Evans
Executor
10
Elizabeth Johnson



The relationship types are just made-up and not intended to have any special significance. The relationships are all one-way. So as it stands, David Jones is the supervisor of Susan Smith. Susan Smith is not the supervisor of David Jones (although she could be, if you add an extra relationship record to that effect).
Here's a quick visualisation

I now have a requirement to be able to list everybody below a certain node in the tree. So for person 1, the list would include 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10. For person 2, the list would be 4, 5, and 6. For person 4, the list would be empty, because there's nobody below them.
I have this recursive CTE
WITH RecursivePeople(RootPeopleId, SourcePeopleId, TargetPeopleId, TreeLevel) AS
(
    SELECT Id,
           NULL,
           Id,
           0
    FROM People
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rp.RootPeopleId,
           pr.SourcePeopleId,
           pr.TargetPeopleId,
           TreeLevel + 1
    FROM PeopleRelationships pr
    JOIN RecursivePeople rp ON rp.TargetPeopleId = pr.SourcePeopleId
    JOIN People p2 ON p2.Id = pr.TargetPeopleId
)
SELECT *
FROM RecursivePeople
ORDER BY RootPeopleId;

That does what I need. "RootPeopleId" is the person I'm interested in, and "TargetPeopleId" is the recursive list of descendants.
Two problems though: (a) duplication, and (b) infinite loops
The results already have duplicate records. If I add
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId)
 VALUES(14,9,2,1);

(adding person 2 below person 9 on the chart), we get even more duplication.
If I add
INSERT INTO PeopleRelationships(Id,SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId,RelationshipTypeId)
 VALUES(15,9,3,1);

(adding person 3 below person 9 on the chart), the query fails altogether because we now have an infinite loop.
I can solve the duplication problem by using a DISTINCT or GROUP BY at the end of the query, and I can sort of solve the infinite loop problem by setting a MAXRECURSION level (but we could theoretically encounter a structure that's deeper than the MAXRECURSION level that I've set). Either way, it feels like we would be processing a lot of records only to throw them away at the end.
Is there some way to control the recursion such that if it runs into a node that it has already seen in the same query, it doesn't go any further down the recursion tree from that node?

See this question from today

Have you considered using SQL Server's Graph Table support instead of trying to reimplement it yourself?

For duplicates - you can apply group by SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId to table People, leaving only one connection (any), before recursion.  To avoid cycles - common way is collect path of traversed rows.

May be usefull remove duplicates from PeopleRelationships before recursive traversing table.
With your data, including 2 addins for check dupplicates and cycle, recursion produces

without grouping  - 86 rows
with pre-grouping - 50 rows

and final output (distinct) is 46 rows.
See example
WITH GrData as(
  select SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId
  from PeopleRelationships
  group by SourcePeopleId,TargetPeopleId
)
,RecursivePeople AS
(
    SELECT Id RootPeopleId,  NULL SourcePeopleId,
           Id TargetPeopleId,
           cast(Id as varchar(100)) path,
           0 TreeLevel
    FROM People
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rp.RootPeopleId,
           pr.SourcePeopleId,
           pr.TargetPeopleId,
           cast(concat(path,'-',pr.SourcePeopleId) as varchar(100)) path,
           TreeLevel + 1
    FROM GrData pr -- PeopleRelationships pr
    JOIN RecursivePeople rp ON rp.TargetPeopleId = pr.SourcePeopleId
    -- JOIN People p2 ON p2.Id = pr.TargetPeopleId
    where charindex(concat('-',pr.TargetPeopleId,'-'),concat('-',path,'-'))=0
)
SELECT DISTINCT RootPeopleId,TargetPeopleId
FROM RecursivePeople
ORDER BY RootPeopleId;

fiddle
and
fiddle

Let's see if adding a safeguard to check if the path was already checked works.
Just be careful and ensure the length of the path string remains manageable, as very long paths could impact performance.
WITH RecursivePeople AS
(
    SELECT 
        Id AS RootPeopleId,
        NULL AS SourcePeopleId,
        Id AS TargetPeopleId,
        0 AS TreeLevel,
        CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Path
    FROM People
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        rp.RootPeopleId,
        pr.SourcePeopleId,
        pr.TargetPeopleId,
        rp.TreeLevel + 1,
        CAST(rp.Path + '|' + CAST(pr.TargetPeopleId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Path
    FROM PeopleRelationships pr
    JOIN RecursivePeople rp 
        ON rp.TargetPeopleId = pr.SourcePeopleId
    -- Prevent revisiting nodes by checking if the TargetPeopleId is already in the Path
    WHERE CHARINDEX('|' + CAST(pr.TargetPeopleId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '|', '|' + rp.Path + '|') = 0
)
-- Select distinct results to remove duplicates
SELECT DISTINCT 
    RootPeopleId,
    TargetPeopleId
FROM RecursivePeople
ORDER BY RootPeopleId, TargetPeopleId

